# How does fillStyle work in bs-webapi Canvas2d

Tags: html5-canvas, reason, bucklescript, bs-webapi

I'm wondering how to create a and set a fill style using bs-webapi and Canvas2d interface in ReasonML.

I think the definition I might need is [this](https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-webapi-incubator/blob/master/src/Webapi/Webapi__Canvas/Webapi__Canvas__Canvas2d.re#L139):

```
let fillStyle = (ctx: t) =>
  ctx |> fillStyle |> reifyStyle;
```

But I'm having trouble understanding it.

I have previously used [this project](https://github.com/af/shmup.re/blob/master/src/StarField.re#L10) as a source of examples, but I think the bs-webapi has changed since that project was authored. At least the following line modeled after the example:

```
Canvas2d.fillStyle(ctx, "rgba(0,255,255,255)");
```

gives me this error:

```
Error: This function has type
         Webapi.Canvas.Canvas2d.t => (Webapi.Canvas.Canvas2d.style('a), 'a)
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you want is `setFillStyle`:

```
Canvas2d.setFillStyle(ctx, String, "rgba(0,255,255,255)");
```

This was renamed from `fillStyle` long ago, because there was no getter back then and the convention is to name the getter `fillStyle` and the setter `setFillStyle`. At the same time it was made to support gradients and pattern.

The way `setFillStyle` now works is that the second argument determines the type of the third. If you pass `String` as the second argument, the third is required to be a `string`. If you pass `Gradient` it needs to be a `gradient`, which you can get from `createLinearGradient` or `createRadialGradient`. And lastly you can pass `Pattern`, which requires the third argument be a `pattern` obtained from `createPattern`.

In general, you should refer to [the Canvas2d test file](https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-webapi-incubator/blob/master/tests/Webapi/Canvas/Webapi__Canvas__Canvas2d__test.re) for usage examples.